# Windows Phone override general PhoneApplicationPage methods application-wide

Tags: navigation, overriding, windows-phone

is it possible to override general PhoneApplicationPage methods ?

In my case I need to run some code every time a new PhoneApplicationPage is opened ( navigated to ) and I dont want to write the same thing in every code behind class.

Thanks, 
Michal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you need to do during the navigation, you can either:

- Subscribe to the [`Navigated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.frame.navigated%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) or [`Navigating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.frame.navigating%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event of the `PhoneApplicationFrame`
- Create an abstract class inheriting from `PhoneApplicationPage`, put your code in there, then make all your pages inherit from that class

Comment: Yes, indeed, Navigated, in particular RootFrame_Navigated in App.xaml.cs will serve my purpose well, thanks